# Android - getting statistics of page loading

Tags: android, http, web

I have a project for an Android app, which basically loads a certain web page (user defined), and show statistics about that page loading and files. 
So basically.

I type: www.imgur.com, the app downloads the site (loads it in background, the process shouldnt be visible), and then the app shows stats like this

Javascript files: 4, load time: 0.3s, size: 30kB

Images: 12, load time: 0.7s, size: 1.5MB

etc.

I already made a few android apps, so I'm rather asking about what to look for? 
My only "tip" is to try to get some browser core (like Chromium) and try to get something from it, but Im really not sure where to grasp it.

I know I could manually "download" that page, but since I need it to also process Javascript and AJAX, so it wont be that easy.

Any tips are very welcome.

Comment: "I'm rather asking about what to look for?" is vague. You should try to narrow down your question to a specific issue/problem and state it in a clear manner. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The problem is, that I'd need some tip where to start, what to look for, since I have no idea. If Id have any more specific issue Id ask it in more specific way.

Comment: In general, to access web pages on Android, you can use a `WebView` or [`HttpURLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). There is at least one library I can think of to help with downloading pages (though I don't remember the name). If you're using `HttpURLConnection`, then if you want to know total page download time and individual times for js and image files, then you would have to follow the links that are found in the HTML data.

Comment: Thank you, at least something to read :)
I also thought I'd just download the links in HTML, but what if there are links that are added by JS? I wont get them, since I cant execute JS... or WebView/HttpURLConnection does this? I'll read the manual, thanks!